# C++ screen capture - how to read the bitmap?

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap, screen, capture

I wanted the program (written in c++) to read the pixels from the screen, but the response I get seems to be messy, the variable **start** indicates the position of the mouse. What is the correct way to do it?
I used the **GetPixel()** which worked fine, but I need a whole bitmap for the efficiency. Here is the code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int nScreenWidth;
int nScreenHeight;

HBITMAP GetScreenBmp(HDC hdc) {
    HDC hCaptureDC  = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, nScreenWidth, nScreenHeight);
    HGDIOBJ hOld = SelectObject(hCaptureDC, hBitmap);
    BOOL bOK = BitBlt(hCaptureDC,0,0,nScreenWidth, nScreenHeight, hdc,0,0,SRCCOPY|CAPTUREBLT);

    SelectObject(hCaptureDC, hOld); // always select the previously selected object once done
    DeleteDC(hCaptureDC);
    return hBitmap;
}

int main() {
    nScreenWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    nScreenHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
    HBITMAP hBitmap;

    int times = 0;
    while (!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SPACE) && times<1000)
    {
        times++;

        POINT p;
        GetCursorPos(&p);

        HDC hdc = GetDC(0);

        hBitmap = GetScreenBmp(hdc);

        BITMAPINFO MyBMInfo = {0};
        MyBMInfo.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(MyBMInfo.bmiHeader);

        if(0 == GetDIBits(hdc, hBitmap, 0, 0, NULL, &MyBMInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS)) {
            cout << "error" << endl;
        }

        BYTE* lpPixels = new BYTE[MyBMInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage];

        MyBMInfo.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;

        if(0 == GetDIBits(hdc, hBitmap, 0, MyBMInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight, (LPVOID)lpPixels, &MyBMInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS)) {
            cout << "error2" << endl;
        }
        //**HERE** - position is wrong?
        int start = (p.y*nScreenWidth+p.x)*4;
        for(int i = start; i < start + 4; i+=4)
        {
            cout << "R:" << (int)lpPixels[i+2] << " G:" << (int)lpPixels[i+1] << " B:" << (int)lpPixels[i] << endl;
        }

        ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);
        delete[] lpPixels;

        Sleep(1000);
    }
    DeleteObject(hBitmap);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does "Seems to be messy" mean? What is the problem you're having?

Comment: I gave you the code to try - I get wrong RGB values, it's not what I have under the mouse at the moment.

Comment: It's up to you to describe your issue as explicitly as possible in the actual question. "Messy" doesn't cut it, and your code doesn't compile, it's missing a brace somewhere.

Comment: @RetiredNinja sorry, I'm unexpirienced - it's my first post here, anyway I fixed the brackets, it will compile now ;)

Comment: You're potentially leaking a lot of bitmaps there.

Comment: Your bitmap is stored upside down. You either need to adjust your mouse coordinates to account for that, or negate the height before you call `GetDIBits`. `MyBMInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight = -MyBMInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight;`

Comment: @RetiredNinja Are you sure that it works for you? Because for me it doesn't - color is not always correct when I move the mouse around, but the position (0,0) seems to be fine.

Comment: @JonathanPotter good point - but hard to fix for me

Comment: I am sure your bitmap is upside down. I changed your program to capture one bitmap when I press the space bar. The color is correct for me. When capturing 1000 bitmaps as fast as you can? *shrug* How would you tell?

Comment: @RetiredNinja Is it my screen resolution settings then? Idk what could went wrong.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I just move the mouse around the black window and the border (where black turns into a different color) seems to be not where I see it. I placed the comment **HERE** - the problem might be there.

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, there is hardly ever a need to use operators `new` or `delete` in C++. Use a `std::vector<BYTE>` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are forcing the compression to be `BI_RGB`, you might as well set the first 6 values and call `GetDIBits` only once. And since the bitmap height starts from bottom to top you have to supply negative height for  `BITMAPINFOHEADER` otherwise read from bottom to top.

Make sure the process is DPI aware. Easiest way (but not the preferred way) is to call `SetProcessDPIAware()`. For each `hBitmap` allocation call `DeleteObject(hBitmap)`

```
int main()
{
    SetProcessDPIAware();
    int width = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    int height = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
    while(!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SPACE))
    {
        HDC hdc = GetDC(0);
        POINT p;
        GetCursorPos(&p);

        HDC memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        HBITMAP hbitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, width, height);
        HGDIOBJ oldbmp = SelectObject(memdc, hbitmap);
        BitBlt(memdc, 0, 0, width, height, hdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY | CAPTUREBLT);
        SelectObject(memdc, oldbmp);
        DeleteDC(memdc);

        //use GetPixel for testing
        COLORREF c = GetPixel(hdc, p.x, p.y);
        printf("%02X%02X%02X\n", GetRValue(c), GetGValue(c), GetBValue(c));

        BITMAPINFO bi = { 0 };
        bi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(bi.bmiHeader);
        bi.bmiHeader.biWidth = width;
        bi.bmiHeader.biHeight = -height;
        bi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32; //32-bit bitmap
        bi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
        bi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;

        //allocate 4 bytes per pixel for 32-bit
        BYTE* lpPixels = new BYTE[height * width * 4]; 
        if(0 != GetDIBits(hdc, hbitmap, 0, height, lpPixels,
            &bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS))
        {
            int i = (p.y * width + p.x) * 4;
            printf("%02X%02X%02X\n\n", 
                        lpPixels[i + 2], lpPixels[i + 1], lpPixels[i + 0]);
        }
        DeleteObject(hbitmap);
        ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);
        delete[] lpPixels;
        Sleep(1000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I cannot even upvote your answer, but thank you, it works ;)